# Is there a bidirectional level converter IC for multiple I/O channels?

Tags: signal, digital-logic

I have two digital devices to connect, both use 20 data lines but one works at 3.3V and the other at 1.8V, and most of the lines are bidirectional. The operating frequency should be at least 5 MHz. I stumbled upon this solution:

http://www.rocketnumbernine.com/2009/04/10/5v-33v-bidirectional-level-converter/

Which seems adequate (provided I make the corresponding changes for the desired voltage levels) but I don't like the fact that it needs 1 IC and 2 resistors for each data line. Does anyone know about an IC that does a similar job but has many channels (ideally 20 or near that) in a single package, or any equivalent solution to the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find a voltage-level translation device with this tool at TI:
http://focus.ti.com/logic/docs/translationselection.tsp?sectionId=458

Answer (score 1):

this PDF should explain what you need for one

http://wwwasic.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/lhcb/Publications/external/AN97055.pdf

as for a single IC i dont know any good candidates, I have seen 6 channel FET arrays

Comment: Thanks, but that's basically the same principle shown at the link I mentioned in my question. The main problem was not how to do, but how to make the circuit compact when you have too many signal lines.

Answer (score 0):

best to split your bidirectional signal into a send and receive line and then you can level shift each individual and do what you need to on the other side with them.  Split them using a open collector transistor or open drain mosfet for the transmit side, and use a driver to pass the signal in the opposite direction for the recieve side.